# Why margin-right is longer than others even when percentage is used

Tags: html, css

HTML code :

```
<div id='boxA' class='box' :class="{boxRed : Aselected}" @click='change("A")'></div>

<div id='boxB' class='box' :class="{boxRed : Bselected}" @click='change("B")'></div>

<div id='boxC' class='box' :class="{boxRed : Cselected}" @click='change("C")'></div>
```

CSS :

```
.box {
width: 50%;
margin: 10%;
padding: 10%;
border: 2px dotted grey;
border-radius: 5px;}
```

OUTPUT :
[image: output]

in the Developers console, the computed CSS value of margin is same on all the sides.
But it seems a little off from the right? What could be the problem??

Comment: 50% + 2*10% + 2*10% = 90% < 100% so your element will be on the left unless you center it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not about margin-right is longer. This is about all element are left aligned.

You can set the margin property to `auto` in `.box` to horizontally center the element .

```
margin: 10% auto;
```

The element will then take up the specified width, and the remaining space will be split equally between the left and right margins.

**Updated snippet :-**

```css
.box {
width: 50%;
margin: 10% auto;
padding: 10%;
border: 2px dotted grey;
border-radius: 5px;}
```

```html
<div id='boxA' class='box' :class="{boxRed : Aselected}" @click='change("A")'></div>

<div id='boxB' class='box' :class="{boxRed : Bselected}" @click='change("B")'></div>

<div id='boxC' class='box' :class="{boxRed : Cselected}" @click='change("C")'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Youir `margin: 10%` is causing the issue. Change it to `margin: 10% auto;`. So it centers perfectly. That's it!

```
.box {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 10%;
  border: 2px dotted grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Adding  Denic Juric`s answer with this ; makes sense

Comment: @NabeelAron Specifying a percentage will result in additional work if you have to amend the `box` `width` in future. So `margin: 10% auto;` would be a better option always. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

If you sum up the width and the margins, you come to the result 70%. The left margin is used, because your elements are floated left. This means that on the right side, after 10% left margin and 50% width, still 30% are left. Thats why the margin on the right looks bigger.

You could use a margin of 25% on the left or center the boxes in order to be centered. Or another approach: set margin left and right to `auto`.